# Chrome Extension webRequest.onBeforeRequest redirect not redirecting

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension to block certain pages on a website.

I do this by loading a .txt file full of the pages to be blocked and then comparing each to the url loaded by the user and then redirecting to a blocking page if the url matches any in the file. However, everything works apart from the actual redirect.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Reddit Subreddit Blocker",
"description": "Blocks access to specified subreddits.",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"],
    "pages": ["blocked.html"],
    "persistent": true
  },
"permissions": [
  "webRequest",
  "*://*.reddit.com/r/*",
  "webRequestBlocking"
]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(details) {
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL("test.txt"), true);
    r.onreadystatechange = function(e){ 
        if (r.readyState == 4 && r.status == 200){              
            var subreddits = r.responseText.split("\n");
            var index;
            var url = details.url;

            var found = false;
            for (index = 0; index < subreddits.length && found == false; ++index){
                if (subreddits[index] === url){
                    console.log("Subreddit found.");
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            if (found == false){
                console.log("not found");
                return {cancel: false};
            }else{
                console.log("redirecting");
                return {redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("blocked.html")};
            }                   
        }
    };
    r.send(null);
}, {
    urls: ["https://*.reddit.com/r/*"]
}, ["blocking"]
);
```

The urls to be blocked are stored on seperate lines in the .txt file.

When I run the code with a url that should be blocked, I simply get the output:

```
Subreddit found.
redirecting
```

Therefore, the subreddit was found and the if statement to redirect was executed but it was not actually redirected.

Comment: You must return in onBeforeRequest itself, not in a nested asynchronous callback. Get the test.txt file contents into a global variable at the start of your background script and simply use it in onBeforeRequest listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm So I need to get test.txt in a separate function, store this in a global variable, and then compare and return in the onBeforeRequest function?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're asking. I thought I was clear enough. Let's wait until someone else posts an answer.